# What is the most up to date IsDefined operator in Rascal?

Tags: rascal

[According to Rascal's documentation](https://www.rascal-mpl.org/docs/Rascal/Statements/Assignment/), the "?" operator can be used to query if a variable is "defined".

For example:

```
int u=1;
int v; // Defined but uninitialised

u = v?2;
```

`v` is uninitialised and therefore `u` will get the value `2`.

However, doing this flags a *"Warning: deprecated feature: run-time check on variable initialisation"*

Hence the question, what is the non-deprecated way to do what the `?` operator did in Rascal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check with the IsDefined operator only things that can in principle be "undefined". Variables are not in that class; they were accidentally and now we are deprecating that behavior. In principle, there exists no `null` or `undefined` value in Rascal.

Having said that there are situations with maps and keyword fields of nodes and algebraic constructors where it is possible that a declared name does not exist at runtime. So:

```
myMap[myKey]?def; // a map does not have to have the key
myCons.myKeywordField?def ; // a keyword field does not have to be set
```

The isDefined operator is part of the assignment syntax on the left-hand side, as explained here: https://www.rascal-mpl.org/docs/Rascal/Statements/Assignment/IsDefined/

Also, the same syntax can be used as an expression: https://www.rascal-mpl.org/docs/Rascal/Expressions/Values/Boolean/IfDefinedElse/

Again, checking variables for undefinedness does not make sense since variables are always defined in Rascal. It is a static error otherwise. Defined but uninitialized variables are for making matching patterns look more elegant:

```
 int i; int j; // here they are declared with a type
 // here they are not defined and may not be used
 if (<i, j> := <1,2>) { // here they are bound/defined
    // here they can be used
 }
 // here i and j are not defined again and may not be used
```

Comment: Thank you for such a clear answer....and for Rascal.